# How use a certificate into NWJS and Linux

Tags: angularjs, node.js, linux, ssl, nwjs

I am making and app with Nwjs and AngularJS, the app is working fine on Windows but now I am trying to export the app to linux("Ubuntu"), but I am getting
a error with the certificate, on Windows I installed the certificate on "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and in that case nwjs is getting all the files
without problem.

I will explain the code that I have now:

in the index file I have something like the following code, in that code I load the "js, css and html" from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/Devel/Main/js/first.js"</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="https://test.com/Devel/Main/css/file.min.css">
```

Like you can see I need load some files from a server in that case I named that "https://test.com".

in the Route file I have:

```
inspection.config(function($routeProvider, $translateProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {

    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',        
        'https://test.com/**'
    ]);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/shipmentInformation/', {
            templateUrl: 'https://test.com/Devel/Main/html/shipmentInformation.html',
            controller: 'shipmentInformationController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

I tried the solution that I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate), after that I can see the certificate into the etc/ssl, then I 
think that the process that I did is correct.

**The problem that I have**

1. I am not sure the equivalent of "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" on Linux
2. Where is reading nwjs the certificates

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation I found that I only need include the certificate into the package of my NW application with the option named "additional_trust_anchors", into that we can include an array of certificates.